# Feed for changed items

Tags: magento-1.9

I am sorry if my question is out of place. I am new to Magento and to this forum and I need some advice.

My application requires that after I make a few changes to my items in Magento (prices, inventory), I would create a feed only to those items that I have changed (since I started the editing).

another option is to create a feed of items that were changed after a specific date/time.

What is the best way to do something like that? 
Is there an extension that has a solution for such an application?

p.s: I am a developer. If there is no readymade solution, I will do it myself.

Answer (score 3):

No idea about readymade solutions, but you could do this easily. Either by having your own script or building a magento controller.

Own script:

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

Mage::getResourcemodel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('updated_at', array('gteq', '2014-01-01'));

foreach($products as $product) {
    // do whatever you want with $product, e.g. echo some of it's data
}
```

Comment: Great solution! If you're running this say every 24 hours might be nice use strtotime() to calculate anything that's changed in the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution proposed by @fabian will work and I vote for it. However, I will share solution I used recently to achieve similar behavior. It covers @hershkoy initial question and it allows to mark product as changed based on checking only particular attributes.

1. create `has_custom_changes` boolean product attribute
2. create custom observer listening on `catalog_product_save_before event`, check if any of your desired attributes has changed its value there using `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::dataHasChangedFor()` method and set `has_custom_changes` to true if it changed.
3. Modify your feed exporter to export only products with `has_custom_changes` flag set to true
4. Reset flag to false after export finishes

Comment: Although I like @Fabian solution because of its simplicity, yours is very close to what I need. Already done #1, and #2. What is feed exporter, and how do you modify it?

Comment: I used commercial extension for that (Go Mage Feed Pro) as I liked other features offered there eg. automated FTP upload. However, I think you can try to use default Magento export which provides ability to export products filtered based on custom product attribute. If it doesn't fit, you could use custom code to prepare such .csv. Do you have your feed export solution ready?